# Karate UI - how to assert the url at the end of the test?

Tags: karate

I'm trying Karate UI testing tool. 
I thought that command "waitForUrl" should fail the test if the url doesn't match. But my test is green even if the url doesn't match. Do I have to use two commands ("waitForUrl" and "match") for failing the test?

My feature file:

```
Feature: web-browser automation

Background:
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }

Scenario: Search for Karate on Google

  Given driver 'https://www.google.com'
  And maximize()
  And delay(2000)
  And input("input[name=q]", 'Karate')
  And click("input[name=btnK]")
  When click("/(//div//a/h3)[1]")
  Then retry(5, 2000).waitForUrl('https://github.com/intuit/karate')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, thanks for finding it. It is fixed in `develop`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1125

Would be great if possibly you can follow the dev guide and see if it works: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide